# cannot download 3rd party plugins in qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

1. I want to download [SDA4PP plug-in in QGIS](http://opensourcegisdevelopment.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/how-to-start-sda4pp-plug-in-in-qgis/). Unfortunately I cannot see the button to download 3rd party plugins, as indicated in the install instructions at that link. I am using this program on a company network. I have put in some proxy settings which mean that I can access the global/official repository. Before I did this I could not even access this. When I go to the plugins tab though there are only a few listed and when I put something in the search box nothing comes up, i.e. it only searches currently downloaded plugins (those that came with the install).

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin is now in the Official Repository, but you have to look for `Spatial Data Analysis` under `name` or `SDA4PP` under `description`. And make sure experimental plugins are activated in the `options` tab.

Volkan Kepoglu’s Repository (as mentioned in the blogpost) has gone...

You can alternatively download the plugin manually from http://pyqgis.org/repo/contributed

Comment: any idea I cannot search for new plugins though? is it likely to be a proxy issue at work? has anyone else reported this type of problem?

Comment: also, are there any other plugins that do Kriging, this one looks to be quite complex

Comment: Yes, might be a proxy issue.